# Setting SSLContext on a CDI injected client using Microprofile

Tags: java, rest, ssl, quarkus, microprofile

I am new to using Microprofile REST clients. I have client which is using `@RegisterRestClient` annotation. I am planning to configure SSL by setting the `SSLContext`. I see from the documentation that truststores and keystores can be specified in the microprofile-config.prroperties, however I don't see a way to initialize/set the SSLContext. I only see a way to set that on a client created programmatically using `RestClientBuilder`